# asserting response body is empty

Tags: node.js, supertest, should.js

I'm trying to assert if response body is empty, but got error:

```
var api = supertest(TEST_URL);
...
api.get('..')
   .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
   .end(function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      res.should.have.status(200);

      // Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to have a property 'length'
      // res.body.should.empty;

      // Workaround should be used
      res.text.should.eql('{}');
```

What's wrong? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How can I assert that body is empty, i.e. sendet with ```res.send()```

Answer (score 1):

`.empty` assertion in `should.js` check for string, arguments, arrays just length property. So if it throw assertion about missing length - your body does not looked parsed to json (you need to make sure you return right `Content-Type` like `application/json`).

For objects yes `.empty` will check for missing any enumerable properties.

```
$ node
> var should = require('should')
undefined
> var res = { body: {} };
undefined
> res.body.should.be.empty
{ obj: {},
  params: { operator: 'to be empty' },
  negate: false }
>
```

Comment: res.type = "application/json", res.text = "{}", res.body = Object, res.should.be.a.json passed

Comment: @hellboy i added example that in REPL it works. So i assume something wrong with your `body` (i used latest should.js 4.0.4).